# file upload zuul proxy request size issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

i have a probleme with zuul proxy, it's about the size of the request, i always getting 500 error Connection has being closed before response.

controller code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController {

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("File Name : " + file.getOriginalFilename(),
            "File Size : " + file.getSize() + "bytes");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(file.getName() + " uploaded");
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to debug with breakpoints? Does it break after print filename or before that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is with the ribbon socket size.
Try to add this properties to your getway properties file -- the one where you enabled zuul proxy -- :

```
ribbon.eager-load.enabled=true
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=3999996
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=999999
ribbon.ReadTimeout=999999
ribbon.SocketTimeout=999999
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=999999
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=999999
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

Comment: i added it on my application properties but i get the same issue

Comment: did you added it on MS service properties file or on MS getway properties file?